# F#: Type matching and active patterns

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, active-pattern

Given the following:

```
type IFruit = interface end

type Avocado = { color : string; age : int } interface IFruit

let (|AvocadoTexture|) (a : Avocado) = if a.age < 7 then "firm" else "mushy"
```

... Why does this work:

```
let texture (f : IFruit) =
    match f with
    | :? Avocado as a -> if a.age < 7 then "firm" else "mushy"
    | _ -> String.Empty
```

... but not this?

```
let texture (fruit : IFruit) =
    match fruit with
    | AvocadoTexture t -> t    // "The type IFruit does not match the type Avocado"
    | _ -> String.Empty
```

Answer (score 6):

`fruit` may be any `IFruit`, but the `AvocadoTexture` Active Pattern only accepts the specific implementation `Avocado`, as per the type annotation of `a`.
If you want the Active Pattern to accept any `IFruit`, but only return a useful value for an `Avocado`, you can make it **partial**:

```
let (|AvocadoTexture|_|) (f : IFruit) =
    match f with
    | :? Avocado as a ->
        if a.age < 7 then "firm" else "mushy"
        |> Some
    | _ -> None
```

Now your `texture` function works as you wanted:

```
let texture (fruit : IFruit) =
    match fruit with
    | AvocadoTexture t -> t
    | _ -> String.Empty
```

Comment: Thank you!  The partial active pattern is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just bear in mind that there are Partial Active Patterns and Active Patterns. Active Patterns have up to 7 tags that something can be concretely matched against. Both forms are useful.

Active Patterns are better if you want the compiler to tell you all the places where you've missed handling a case after you've decided that you need an extra one. The compiler can be configured to flag this as an error rather than a warning if you want to be extra strict about it.

```
open System

type IFruit = interface end

type Avocado = 
  { color : string; age : int } 
  interface IFruit
  static member tryFromIFruit(x:IFruit) = 
    match x with
    | :? Avocado -> Some(x:?>Avocado)
    | _ -> None

let (|Firm|Mushy|) (a : Avocado) = if a.age < 7 then Firm else Mushy

let texture (fruit : IFruit) =
    match fruit |> Avocado.tryFromIFruit with  // we're not sure if it's an Avocado.
    | Some(Firm) -> "firm"                     // use Some(SomethingElse()) when you want to collapse an extra layer of "match" statements.
    | Some(Mushy) -> "mushy"
    | None -> ""

texture ( { color = "green"; age = 4 } :> IFruit)
```

documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns